# Windows Phone 7 Application - INPC problems

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm

I am doing a WP7 application for the first time and I am trying to use MVVM pattern.
I am making an alarm clock and this is what I have:

View - MainView.xaml

```
...
 <TextBox Text="{Binding Hour, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
...
```

Model - AlarmClock.cs:

```
...

private string _second = 22;
  public string Second {
        get { return _second; }
        set {
            _second = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Second");
        }
    }
...
```

ViewModel - MainViewModel.cs

```
...
private AlarmClock alarmClock;

public MainViewModel() {
    alarmClock = new AlarmClock();
}

public string Second {
        get { return alarmClock.Second; }
        set {
            alarmClock.Second = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Second");
        }
    }
```

In the MainView.xaml.cs i set the data context to be
this.DataContext = new ViewModel();

Both ViewModel and Model implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

And my problem is: In the Model I have a DispatcherTimer that ticks every second. When I do this:

Second = 23;

My view (my textbox) is not updating and does not show the value of _second. But if I write something in the textbox, then it seems like my model is updated with the value that is typed.

Can someone see what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance,
Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property names and types given in your example are a little bit confusing but I think the main problem in your case is the following:

You have a property with the type `AlarmClock` in your `MainViewModel`. You have a `MainViewModel` instance as the `DataContext` for the `MainView.xaml`. I see you delegate the `Second` property of the `MainViewModel` to the `AlarmClock` instance. This is great when the change comes from the UI but I think your DispatcherTimer operates on the `AlarmClock` instance but that instance doesn't have any observer (because the UI listens to the `MainViewModel` instance).

You have more than one options to make it work, but my suggestion to this situation is to extend the TextBox binding path and bind it directly to the `AlarmClock` instance. Of course you need to expose the `AlarmClock` on the `MainViewModel`:

```
private AlarmClock alarmClock;

public MainViewModel() {
    alarmClock = new AlarmClock();
}

public AlarmClock AlarmClock 
{
    get { return alarmClock; }
}
```

then change your xaml:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding AlarmClock.Hour, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
```

Another option is to subscribe to the `AlarmClock` instances `PropertyChanged` event inside the `MainViewModel` an delegate that to the UI, but that is messy. You could also change the DispatcherTimer to operate on the `MainViewModel` but I don't think that belongs there.